# Correct type for Form component action in react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'm building an app to learn the new React router (v6.14.1) and I'm using typescript.

I'm trying to build a form using the react-router-dom `<Form />` component.

I have my code working, but I had to define the action function prop to any, as seen bellow.

```js
export const createTruck = async ({ request }: any) => {
  const data = await request.formData()

  const submission = {
    make: data.get('make'),
    model: data.get('model'),
    plate: data.get('plate'),
    year: data.get('year'),
    km: data.get('km'),
    buy_date: data.get('buy_date'),
    last_maint: data.get('last_maint'),
    next_maint_d: data.get('next_maint_d'),
    next_maint_km: data.get('next_maint_km'),
  }

  console.log(submission)

  return redirect('/trucks')
}
```

What is the correct type I should define `request` as?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [action](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/router/utils.ts#L169-L174) function is typed as:

> ```
> /**
>  * Route action function signature
>  */
> export interface ActionFunction {
>     (args: ActionFunctionArgs): Promise<Response> | Response | Promise<any> | any;
> }
> ```

The action `args` is type [`ActionFunctionArgs`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/router/utils.ts#L150-L153):

> ```
> /**
>  * @private
>  * Arguments passed to route loader/action functions.  Same for now but we keep
>  * this as a private implementation detail in case they diverge in the future.
>  */
> interface DataFunctionArgs {
>     request: Request;
>     params: Params;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Arguments passed to action functions
>  */
> export interface ActionFunctionArgs extends DataFunctionArgs {
> }
> ```

The `ActionFunctionArgs` is the type you want to import and specify if your Typescript configuration can't already infer the correct type.

Example:

```js
import { redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import type { ActionFunctionArgs } from 'react-router-dom';

export const createTruck = async ({ request }: ActionFunctionArgs) => {
  const data = await request.formData();

  const submission = {
    make: data.get('make'),
    model: data.get('model'),
    plate: data.get('plate'),
    year: data.get('year'),
    km: data.get('km'),
    buy_date: data.get('buy_date'),
    last_maint: data.get('last_maint'),
    next_maint_d: data.get('next_maint_d'),
    next_maint_km: data.get('next_maint_km'),
  };

  console.log(submission);

  return redirect('/trucks');
};
```